# Why can't I use the else statement here for javascript?

Tags: javascript

Why do I keep getting error, unexpected else token?

```
var PRIZES = ["a new car", "a broken stapler", "a refrigerator"];
var door = prompt("Choose a door number (1,2,or3)");
var prize = PRIZES[door - 1];

if (prize <= 3 && prize >= 1);{
    alert("you have won " + prize.toUpperCase() + "!!");
}  
else (door === undefined); { alert("not a door"); }
```

Comment: You are looking for `else if`.

Comment: Being a "noob" is no excuse for not googling how to use else in javascript

Answer (score 3):

Don't put semi-colons after the if and else statements. Only use them at the end of statements. Additionally, you need to use `else if` and not `else` in order to check another conditional expression. You also need to check if the `door`—not the `prize`—is `<= 3` and `>= 1` like so:

```
var PRIZES = ["a new car", "a broken stapler", "a refrigerator"];
var door = prompt("Choose a door number (1,2,or3)");
var prize = PRIZES[door - 1];

if (door <= 3 && door >= 1)
{
    alert("you have won " + prize.toUpperCase() + "!!");
}  
else if (door === undefined) 
{ 
    alert("not a door"); 
}
```

By the way, it looks like you should just get rid of that `else if (door === undefined)` and replace it with just an `else`. I would also suggest parsing `door` as an integer.

Answer (score 1):

because you're using a conditional for the `else`. `else` is meant to be a catch all if the `if` condition is not met. For your needs use an `else if`:

```
var PRIZES = ["a new car", "a broken stapler", "a refrigerator"];
var door = prompt("Choose a door number (1,2,or3)");
var prize = PRIZES[door - 1];
if (prize <= 3 && prize >= 1);{
    alert("you have won " + prize.toUpperCase() + "!!");
}  
else if (door === undefined) {
    alert("not a door");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we should just put it into simple terms like this

```
if () {

} else {

}
```

or

```
if () {

} else if () {

} else if () {

} else () {

}
```

there isnt semi colons ; after the (), in fact you can most likely just skip all the semi colon in javascript since it will be automatically added, i normaly only puts one right in the beginning of a js file like this

```
;(function(){})()
```

the other time you would needed is in a loop,

```
for ( ; i < len; i++) {}
```